# Access the selected bound field values from Gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net

My gridview is defined as

```
<asp:GridView ID="gv1" runat="server">
<Columns>
    <asp:TemplateField>
        <HeaderTemplate>
            <asp:CheckBox ID="chk1" runat="server" />
        </HeaderTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
    <asp:BoundField DataField="name" HeaderText="Name" SortExpression="name" ReaadOnly="true" />
</Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

How can I access the selected Boundfield from  Code Behind?

Answer (score 3):

Handle the `SelectedIndexChanged` event.

In the code-behind:

```
var name = gv1.SelectedRow.Cells[1].Text;
```

Comment: Is there a way we can access the value based on the BoundField DataField name   like gv1.SelectedRow.DataItem() ?

Comment: This example is probably what you're looking for: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridviewrow.dataitem.aspx